# Where on-line can I find a GIS land use .lyr that shows standard colors for each land use code?

Tags: land-use

I have been looking on-line for a GIS land use layer file that shows all the standard colors that represents each land use code.  I have not been successful in finding that.  Would you please direct me to where I can find this layer file on-line?

Comment: Please don't use thanks in advance in your question, please give thanks by voting on answers.  in relation to your question, are you certain that standard colours exist for land-use (globally) or have you seen a map of land-use somewhere and would like to use those colours.  Please edit your question to add more details.

Comment: are saying there is a global standard for land use codes/colors? I have not seen this. It is important to be consistent if you're using a color schema to represent land use but for your maps only not a global standard i do not think there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not see any standards for land use classification in general because it depends on each country's standard. You need to refer to the standards applied in Ministry of land or Land Bureau in the target country and ask them to give you the color standards applied in their organization.

For example, the [American Planning Association](https://www.planning.org/lbcs/standards/) defines its own standard, as you can see in the PDF Document: [Land-Based Classification Standards](https://planning-org-uploaded-media.s3.amazonaws.com/legacy_resources/lbcs/standards/pdf/InOneFile.pdf). Another example in Cambodia, they also defines their own land use standard in this document: [Traditional Color Coding for Land Uses](http://www.gismanual.com/style/ColorConventions.pdf). The same can be found in each country's related organization as stated earlier.